# Unknown record property / related component "..." on "..." with sfDoctrineActAsTaggablePlugin

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-1.4, acts-as-taggable

I'm using the symfony plugin sfDoctrineActAsTaggablePlugin to add a Taggable behaviour to some objects of my model.

I followed the instruction given [here](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfDoctrineActAsTaggablePlugin) but when I want to save a taggable element in the database I get :

```
Unknown record property / related component "saved_tags" on "Mishidea"
```

Mishidea is the name of the class/table that I want to be taggable. Here is the related portion of my schema.yml file:

```
Mishidea:
  connection: doctrine
  actAs: {Timestampable: ~ , Taggable: ~ }      
  tableName: mishidea
  columns:
    idea_id:
      type: integer(4)
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    idea_title:
      type: string()
      notnull: true
      primary: false
    idea_summary:
      type: string()
      notnull: true
      primary: false
    idea_description:
      type: string()
      notnull: true
      primary: false
    idea_up:
      type: integer(8)
      notnull: true
      default: 0
      primary: false
    idea_down:
      type: integer(8)
      notnull: true
      default: 0
      primary: false
    idea_confirmation:
      type: boolean(1)
      default: false
      primary: false
    group_id:
      type: integer(4)
      notnull: false
      primary: false
  relations:
    Mishgroup:
      local: group_id
      foreign: group_id
      type: one
    Ideacomment:
      local: idea_id
      foreign: idea_id
      type: many
    Mishdocument:
      local: idea_id
      foreign: idea_id
      type: many
    RelIdeafollower:
      local: idea_id
      foreign: idea_id
      type: many
```

Note that I also tried:

```
actAs:
    Timestampable: ~
    Taggable: ~
```

and:

```
actAs:[Timestampable,Taggable]
```

instead of:

```
actAs: {Timestampable: ~ , Taggable: ~ }
```

but both alternatives produce the same result.

It seems like the relation between the taggable element and the tagging table is not etablished...

Does anyone know anything about the "Unknown record property / related component" error in general of about this particular problem with the Taggable behaviour?

Some help would be much appreciated.

If that helps I'm using Symfony 1.4 with MySQL/InnoDB and have also tried with PostgreSQL with the same result.

Thanks

FuzzyTern